# updating a different model in one form while creating new records of different model on the same form in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a model named Houses with a field named status to keep track of occupied/not occupied houses. and another model named occupancy. When a tenant is being assigned a new house I want to change the value of that particular house from 'not occupied' to 'occupied' on the occupancy's form.
Here's the part of the controller I have been using

```
  namespace app\controllers;

        use Yii;
        use app\models\Occupancypayments; 
        use app\models\Houses;
        use app\models\OccupancypaymentsSearch;
        use yii\web\Controller;

         /**
         * Creates a new Occupancypayments model.
         * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected   'view'    page.
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function actionCreate()
        {
            $hse = 'u4';

            $model = new Occupancypayments;

            if (isset($_POST['houseNumber'])) {

                $hse = $_POST['houseNumber'];
                }

            $house = Houses::find()->where(['houseNo'=>$hse])->one();

            if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

                      $model->save();
               return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' =>$model->transactionNo]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [ 
                        'model' => $model,
                        'house' => $house,
                 ]);
            }
        }
```

and here's the form for occupancy

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'teenantName')->textInput() ?>




 <?=  $form->field($model, 'propertyID')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Propertydetails::find()->all(), 'propertyId', 'propertyName'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'choose property ...','id'=>'propertyId'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
   ]);?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'propertyName')->textInput(['maxlength' => 20]) ?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'houseNumber')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options'=>['id'=>'houseNumber'], 
    'pluginOptions'=>[
    'depends'=>['propertyId'], // the id for cat attribute
    'placeholder'=>'Select house...',
    'url'=> Url::to(['occupancypayments/subcat']) 
    ]
    ]); ?>

    <!--set the selected  house number to occupied -->
    <?= $form->field($house, 'status')->dropDownList([ 'ocupied' => 'Ocupied', 'not ocupied' => 'Not ocupied', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'houseDepoDue')->textInput() ?>
```

I want to change the house status of the specific selected house. 
Now the problem is when I hard code the houseNo in the controller works just fine. But when I try to get the selected house using

```
     $_GET[houseNumber]
```

and assign that to a variable then use it in the making the $house object, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Firts don't refer directly to super variable $_GET or $_POST use instead

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
```

Second i guess the data are submitted by a post method then the data value are store in :

```
$post['Houses']
$post['Occupancypayments']
```

Comment: thanks so much but am getting this error . undefined index Occupancypayments. Even if I use $post['houseNumber'] same error. Undefined index houseNumber

Comment: You must test `if (isset($post['Houses']))`  before you accessing to the POST data. If the POST is not setting because is a preliminary action these value are not setting, you must test it and when you receive the POST answer you can access to values.

Comment: i have this and is giving me a blank page  if(isset($post['Occupancypayments']))
        {
              $hse = $post['Occupancypayments']['houseNumber'];   
              $house = Houses::find()->where(['houseNo'=>$hse])->one();

Comment: Check with an echo o var_dump the content of $hse,  if   is null this mean you don't submit the corresponding values if is not nul check the data for query